# Magento 2 : How to write controller to load category page?

Tags: category, magento-2.1, layered-navigation, category-products, category-view

I have customized a Layered navigation modules in Magento 2. However, I can't write a controller to get all content of category page and load into controller page(`localhost/magento2/layerednavigation/index/index/id/17?cat=15&style_general=117`).

The controller page will load but it don't filler product. I have checked and seen that controller page don't get param(cat, style_general....).
Summary, I want write controller to load category page. However, I am facing the issue is the filler don't work into controller page.

**Please refer code:**
1. Code for layout: **layerednavigation_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">8</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">9</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
                        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
                    </action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>
            <argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Rss\Link" name="rss.link" template="Magento_Catalog::category/rss.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Controller code: index.php

   ```
   <?php
    namespace Emthemes\LayeredNavigationPro\Controller\Index;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

   class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {
   protected $_coreRegistry = null;

   protected $_catalogSession;

   protected $_catalogDesign;

   protected $_storeManager;

   protected $categoryUrlPathGenerator;

   protected $resultPageFactory;

   protected $resultForwardFactory;

   private $layerResolver;

   protected $categoryRepository;

   /**
    * Constructor
    *
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
    * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator
    * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
    * @param Resolver $layerResolver
    * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
    */
   public function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign,
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
   \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
   \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
   \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
   PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
   \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
   Resolver $layerResolver,
   CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
   ) {
   parent::__construct($context);
   $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
   $this->_catalogDesign = $catalogDesign;
   $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
   $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
   $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator = $categoryUrlPathGenerator;
   $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
   $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
   $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
   $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
   }

   /**
    * Initialize requested category object
    *
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
    */
   protected function _initCategory()
   {
   $categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
   if (!$categoryId) {
       return false;
   }

   try {
       $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
   } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
       return false;
   }
   if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category')->canShow($category)) {
       return false;
   }
   $this->_catalogSession->setLastVisitedCategoryId($category->getId());
   $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_category', $category);
   try {
       $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
           'catalog_controller_category_init_after',
           ['category' => $category, 'controller_action' => $this]
       );
   } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
       $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
       return false;
   }

   return $category;
   }

   /**
    * Category view action
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
    */
   public function execute()
   {
   if ($this->_request->getParam(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
       return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
   }
   $category = $this->_initCategory();
   if ($category) {
       $this->layerResolver->create(Resolver::CATALOG_LAYER_CATEGORY);
       $settings = $this->_catalogDesign->getDesignSettings($category);

       // apply custom design
       if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
           $this->_catalogDesign->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
       }

       $this->_catalogSession->setLastViewedCategoryId($category->getId());

       $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
       // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
       if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
           $page->getConfig()->setPageLayout($settings->getPageLayout());
       }

       $hasChildren = $category->hasChildren();
       if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
           $type = $hasChildren ? 'layered' : 'layered_without_children';
       } else {
           $type = $hasChildren ? 'default' : 'default_without_children';
       }

       if (!$hasChildren) {
           // Two levels removed from parent.  Need to add default page type.
           $parentType = strtok($type, '_');
           $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $parentType]);
       }
       $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $type, 'id' => $category->getId()]);

       // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
       $layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates();
       if ($layoutUpdates && is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
           foreach ($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
               $page->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
               $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['layout_update' => md5($layoutUpdate)]);
           }
       }

       $page->getConfig()->addBodyClass('page-products')
           ->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category))
           ->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getUrlKey());

       } 
       $block = $page->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products');
       $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is get category id from url and set in registery and use it in block,
This is what controller execute contains:

```
$catId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
$this->_coreRegistry->register('catid', $catId);
```

Here is the block function where you can access your registery category id and using it just fetch all categories :

Initialization:

```
       protected $_coreRegistry;
       private $_itemCollectionFactory;
```

Constructor :

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoriesCollection,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_itemCollectionFactory = $categoriesCollection;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    ...
}
```

And here is the function to get category list:

```
public function getCategoriesList()
{
    $cid = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('catid');

    $categoryFactory = $this->_itemCollectionFactory->create()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    return $categoryFactory;
}
```

Comment: i have yet to filter into controller page. Could you show the instruction for me? Thanks for your help. I am a new Magento.

Comment: you can fetch category id from url in controller execute method, have you tried?

Comment: I have tried. However, it doesn't have respond. Could you help me, please?

Comment: sure, 
simply copy this line:
   `$catId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('cat', false);`

and print $catId and check what you are getting.
you need to put this in controller execute method.

Comment: I have performed like you have guided. It don't effect to filter into controller page.

Comment: it will not filter anything bro, It just fetch Id from url, after yjay you need to add it in registery . n then access that registery into block and you can set filter in block.